# Why does my Makefile give a 'CreateProcess' error when trying to move files in Windows?

Tags: windows, makefile

How do I move files using make in Windows?

Here's my target :

```
source.o : source.c 
   gcc source.c -c -I../include/source -Wall 
   move source.o ..\bin\
```

I get an make error :
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, move source.o "..\bin ", ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.

Do I need to give the Makefile some kind of permission?

When I run the " move " command on cmd it works.

Comment: What is `move` ? Did you mean `mv`?

Comment: Moving the target that the rule has just been built doesn't make a lot of sense from a Makefile target dependency point of view.

Comment: `move` is a builtin command in cmd, not an executable. (Try to execute `move.exe` in cmd and see it fail.) `make` does not use cmd for executing the steps.

Comment: If what you want to build is `../bin/source.o` then write a rule for *that*, not for `source.o`, an altogether different file.  You can avoid moving the compiler's output after it is built by telling the compiler where you want the output.  Idiomatic (with gcc, at least) would be to add `-o $@`  to the `gcc` command to make it put its result in whatever file the rule's target designates.

Comment: Are you using make or nmake? make uses the Bourne-like shell (usually `/bin/sh`) configured by the `SHELL` variable to execute commands in Makefile rules. I guess nmake uses `cmd.exe` to execute commands in Makefile rules or perhaps it uses a built-in command processor.